# Difference between tunneling to localhost and sharing IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, localhost, ip-address

There are some gems such as [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com) that say they tunnel to your localhost, so I can run my application on my localhost and use their gem to make it public to other testers, etc. so they can try it from, for example, their homes. However, I don't understand one thing: What is the difference between that and just giving them my computer's IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your IP is not public, most likely you are behind a router and have a private IP address.
Also, your server is started on `localhost` in the development environment which is essentially inaccessible from the internet.

You can achieve something similar to using tunnelling if you setup port forwarding on your router.